# Need help to open. deb file

Tags: software-installation

I'm new to Linux btw. I accidentally set it so if I open .deb file, it will take me to Terminal, I've installed Gdebi, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on a .deb and choose open with (or similar). Should be a checkbox for setting that option as default.

Also, I would suggest [Eddy](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.eddy/) instead of Gdebi for eOS.

Comment: Ouw ok, so you have to touch it with two fingers on touchpad for right click, and thanks for the suggestion